# ¿Como mostrar una petición sin mostrar la forma en la misma página en PHP?

Tags: php, linux

Estoy desarrollando una calculadora en PHP y quiero que cuando se realice la petición de la operación solamente muestre el resultado en la página y que muestre una opcion para regresar, pero al momento de enviar la consulta el navegador solo muestra el código fuente

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET)): ?>
  $valor1=$_GET['valor1'];
  $valor2=$_GET['valor2'];
  $operacion=$_GET['operacion'];

switch($operacion){

  case 1:
    $total=$valor1+$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es : ".$total;   
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;
  case 2:
    $total=$valor1-$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es: ".$total;
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;
  case 3:
    $total=$valor1*$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es: ".$total;
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;
  case 4:
    $total=$valor1/$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es: ".$total;
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;    
}
<?php else:?>

<br>
<br>
<center>

<h2>Operaciones de 2 numeros</h2>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"; method='get'>
<input name='valor1'>
<br>
<input name='valor2'>
 <br>
  <select name='operacion'>
    <option value='1'>Suma</option>
    <option value='2'>Resta</option>
    <option value='3'>Multi</option>
    <option value='4'>Divi</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
  </form>

<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Si te esta mostrando el código fuente es porque al parecer no esta corriendo en el servidor.**

Envía el link que colocas en el navegador cuando pruebas tu calculadora

---

Mira la imagen de la respuesta del link que me enviaste y si hago la operacion sirve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: acabo de utilizar ese link y funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes, la solucion que yo te propongo es la siguiente, haz en un documento el formulario:

**FORMULARIO HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Operaciones de 2 numeros</h2>
        <form action="newEmptyPHP.php" method='get'>
<input name='valor1'>
<br>
<input name='valor2'>
 <br>
  <select name='operacion'>
    <option value='1'>Suma</option>
    <option value='2'>Resta</option>
    <option value='3'>Multi</option>
    <option value='4'>Divi</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
  </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

y en otro enlazado en el `<form action>` realizas el `PHP` tal que así:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET)){ 
  $valor1=$_GET['valor1'];
  $valor2=$_GET['valor2'];
  $operacion=$_GET['operacion'];
}

switch($operacion){

  case 1:
    $total=$valor1+$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es : ".$total;   
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;
  case 2:
    $total=$valor1-$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es: ".$total;
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;
  case 3:
    $total=$valor1*$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es: ".$total;
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;
  case 4:
    $total=$valor1/$valor2;
    echo "El resultado es: ".$total;
    echo "<br><a href='home.php'>Regresar</a>";
    break;    
}

?>
```

Lo he probado, a mi me funciona bien de esta manera y hace lo que pides, un saludo y ánimo.